# fail to deplay WAR on tomcat 9

Tags: java, xml, maven, tomcat

Before deploy this project, every project deploys just fine. But deploying this project on my tomcat, it get errors. I get no error by running its maven install and maven test. I try every thing on stack overflow, but still not working. Any suggestion will be appreciate. I'll upload any information if I missed. Thanks a lot.

here is the error I got on catalina.2018-08-06.log on tomcat 9.0.8
    06-Aug-2018 16:33:32.228 error [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@45956aaa]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)

```
06-Aug-2018 16:33:32.230 error [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive [C:\ML\Tools\apache-tomcat-9.0.8\webapps\cubGate.war]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@45956aaa]

06-Aug-2018 16:33:32.233 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [C:\ML\Tools\apache-tomcat-9.0.8\webapps\cubGate.war] has finished in [322] ms
```

here is the code I got running maven test

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building cubGate 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ cubGate ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (MS950 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\ML\workspace1\cubGate\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ cubGate ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ cubGate ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (MS950 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\ML\workspace1\cubGate\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ cubGate ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ cubGate ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.699 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-08-06T17:52:25+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/155M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

`

Comment: are you copying the war on already running `tomcat`?

Comment: no, It still not good after I restart tomcat. on manage app of tomcat, it says deploy failed and can't start it.

Comment: The problem is this error in the Tomcat log: **ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)**. So you may have one or more corrupt jar files in the project you are deploying. If you have successfully deployed that project before then focus on what has changed since the last successful deployment. If no jar files have been updated or added since the last deployment then the problem may be with your war file itself. Try opening your war file and/or any jar files it contains with some zip file utility such as 7-Zip. It will report an error when opening a corrupt war or jar.